# Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4 Hiding elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I try to migrate from bootstrap3 to bootstrap4. It is extremly painful and the online converters do not work at all.

E.g. I even fail to convert the following bootstrap 3 block to bootstrap 4

```css
body {
  min-height: 1200px;
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.header {
/*    border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;*/
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.one-edge-shadow {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
         box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid header one-edge-shadow">
    <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="position: absolute;">
            <h3 class="centerText">Dashboard</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 hidden-lg hidden-md">
            <center><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x80"></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Attempt:**

```css
body {
  min-height: 1200px;
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.header {
/*    border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8;*/
    font-family: arial;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 100;
    background: white;
    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.one-edge-shadow {
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
         box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.centerText {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid header one-edge-shadow">
    <div class="row" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 d-md-none d-sm-none d-xs-none" style="position: absolute;">
            <h3 class="centerText">Dashboard</h3>
        </div>

        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1 d-sm-none d-xs-none">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 d-lg-none d-md-none">
            <center><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x80"></center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/)

Please execute the examples and press on "Full page".

Comment: `col-xs` and `d-xs` etc. are now just `col` and `d`

Comment: Also please read this very carefully, as display classes now work in an other way: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

Comment: I already readed the article carefully and even linked to the exact same article in my question. But it does just not work for me as you can see.

Comment: It does work: https://www.codeply.com/go/Zhmvlh4Bvv if you correctly follow the Bootstrap docs and dup question.